# Apply Style to raster through QGIS Processing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have to apply style(qml file) to raster . I am doing this with Qgis processing script ,

```
 import processing 
 input ='E:/data/input.tif'
 style_layer='E:/data/newStyleqgis.qml'
 output_file = 'E:/data/abcde.tif'
 processing.runalg("qgis:setstyleforrasterlayer", input,style_layer)
```

but their is not a option to generate output, style is set but not applied.

```
  ALGORITHM: Set style for raster layer
  INPUT <ParameterRaster>
  STYLE <ParameterFile>
  OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
```

is their any option to save it with the style loaded raster or to pass output as a parameter ,so it will save at path specified.
Using the script from c# program.

Updates Script :

```
  from PyQt4.QtCore import *
  from qgis.core import *
  import qgis.utils
  import processing
  layer = "E:/data/abc.tif"
  output = "E:/data/xyz.tif"
  fileInfo = QFileInfo(layer)
  baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
  filename ='abc.tif'
  rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(filename, baseName)
  # Define the minimum extent of the region
  style_layer='E:/data/newStyleqgis.qml'
  processing.runalg("qgis:setstyleforrasterlayer", layer, style_layer)
  extent = rlayer.extent()
  xmin = extent.xMinimum()
  xmax = extent.xMaximum()
  ymin = extent.yMinimum()
  ymax = extent.yMaximum()
  width =  rlayer.width()
  height =  rlayer.height()
 renderer = rlayer.renderer()
 provider= rlayer.dataProvider()
 crs = rlayer.crs().toWkt()
 pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
 pipe.set(provider.clone())
 pipe.set(renderer.clone())
 file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(output)
 file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,width,height,extent,layer.crs())
```

showing error :NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'

Comment: Not sure if you can save rasters with a specific style as when they are loaded into QGIS, their style is automatically set to the default `Singleband gray`.

Comment: yes , if it is not saved then it happen so.. but if a layer is saved after style is loaded then whenever we load in qgis style  will remains.

Comment: Sounds like you want to save your raster as a **rendered image**. Perhaps this post might help: [QGis Save Raster as Rendered Image](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68803/qgis-save-raster-as-rendered-image)

Comment: this post have some code like layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = layer.extent()  but i am not loading layer in qgis . i am doing the process from standalone script using proceesing .

Comment: [Check this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210922/error-running-grass-module-in-qgis-python-console/211134#211134) on how to get the raster layer and its extent in a standalone script (ignore the processing part).

Comment: updated my script as post help about the extent but some other error appears. ':NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone' .. updated script is included in above Question .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49466/discussion-between-user18-and-joseph).